# How to Correctly show component sizes in inno component page

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I am not getting the correct memory sizes of all the component selected in the component page.

Please give me a solution how the total memory selected for all the components should be correct?

The memory size is displayed on the label at the bottom of the page.

Comment: in the select component page, i have different components to install and the memory size is coming incorrect in total when you select more than one component in the check boxes.

Comment: have u tried some thing code? paste here if any

Comment: No i have not tried any code

Comment: i am getting incorrect memory size of all components selected in the select components page. the label at the bottom of the page  shows incorrect size when you check multiple components.

Comment: Any help on the above issue

Comment: which type of component you are selecting?

Comment: please find the attached image of the component page

Comment: How "incorrect" is it? The total label shows the minimum required space that it know it will use. It also excludes the extra items that are included in multiple components.

Comment: Related question: [How to get memory size of the selected components in the select component page in inno setup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21825424/588306)

Answer (score 0):

If in the [files] section check flags are used, not all flags can be processed by Inno-setup. Especially if you created check flags which rely on the [code] section.

In my setup a created an array of all files.
In this record I have a selected flag, and a filesizeflag.
An example looks like:

```
 files[index].selected := // true or false depending on your wizard flow 
 files[index].filesize := {#filesize(..)} // on the .. the source file, including path
```

Before calling the dir page wizard page you go through a procedure which counts the file sizes and adds them to the file size already counted.
Yhe file size already counted is for every setup different, depending how much code you have in the code section is my experience.

My example code for counting the space is a good start (I hope)

```
Procedure GetSetUsedDiskSpace();
// This procedure counts an displays the used disk space
{}
var
 TempS, SearchString, NumberString, diskspace : String;
 Position, p2                                 : Integer;
 Tot_disk, TempSpace                          : Longint;
 {}
 begin
  TempS        := InitDiskSpace; // wizardform.DiskSpaceLabel.Caption;
  SearchString := 'MB';
  Position     := pos(SearchString, TempS);
  NumberString := copy(TempS, 1, Position-2); // exclusive the space before the MB
  p2           := 0;
  repeat // find the space before the number
   p2           := pos(' ', NumberString);
   NumberString := copy(NumberString, p2 + 1, length(NumberString) - p2);
  until p2 = 0;
  p2 := pos(',', NumberString);
  if (p2 = 0) then
   begin // Some languages use the period as a decimal separator
    p2 := pos('.', NumberString);
   end;
  if (p2 > 0) then
   begin
    NumberString := copy(Numberstring, 1, p2-1) + copy(NumberString, p2+1, 1);
    // If there is a need to more shifting we add some code
   end;
  TempSpace := StrToInt(NumberString);
  TempSpace := TempSpace * 1024 * 1024; // Conversion to bytes
  TempSpace := TempSpace / 10;          // We replaced the decimal separator once
  CountSpace;                           // Count the space for our selection
  Tot_disk      := UsedDiskSpace + TempSpace; // The total in bytes
  UsedDiskSpace := Tot_disk;                  // We need this for the control panel
  Tot_disk      := Tot_disk / 1024;           // The total in kilobytes
  Tot_disk      := Tot_disk / 1024;           // The total in MB
  diskspace     := IntToStr(Tot_disk);
  TempS         := SetupMessage(msgDiskSpaceMBLabel);
  StringChangeEx(TempS, '[mb]', diskspace, True);
  WizardForm.DiskSpaceLabel.Caption := TempS;
 end;
```