# How to get memory size of the selected components in the select component page in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have some components in the component page . when i select any component it should show the memory size of the selected component  in a message box. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Related question: [How to Correctly show component sizes in inno component page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21694654/588306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible (or could be but in a very, very difficult way). The component size is stored internally in the [`TSetupComponentEntry`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Projects/Struct.pas#L174) record in each component item `ItemObject`, which is due to a lack of missing pointer support impossible to access directly.

Comment: is there any way to hide the label at bottom of the page which shows size of the selected components?

Comment: Yes, `WizardForm.ComponentsDiskSpaceLabel.Visible := False;`. But what is the aim of all of this anyway ?

Comment: I need this option because we run a a lot of scripts for updates and other stuff.Inno cant calculate how much memory will be used after the batch-script (copying ...). Thats the reason our calculated componentsize is wrong.

Comment: @kdoteu, I see your needs, but I'm sorry; it's not upon me (I'm not the Inno Setup developer). Try to ask for this feature on the official newsgroup.

Comment: @TLama  i know you're not the developer. I used your "solution". Its better to show nothing, then wrong informations.